# app.config - configuration system failed to initialize with custom section

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, web-config, app-config

I've got a web api where I've added a custom section into the web.config as per this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx. My web.config looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please 
  visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="productGroup">
      <section
       name="product"
       type="myProject.Stuff.Api.ProductSection"
       allowLocation="true"
       allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- various app settings -->
  </appSettings>
  <productGroup>
    <product name="my name" id="1" />
    <product name="my name 2" id="2" />
  </productGroup>

<!-- other standard elements -->

</configuration>
```

I added in the configSections and the productGroup. I then define a c# class as ProductSection as follows:

using System.Configuration;

```
namespace myProject.Stuff.Api
{
    public class ProductSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this["name"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["name"] = value;
            }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("id", IsRequired = true)]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)this["id"];
            }
            set
            {
                this["id"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've copied the 2 sections across to my app.config in my test project, but when I now try and debug a test I get the failed to initialize error. When I comment out the productGroup section it then stops complaining. What have I done wrong?

***UPDATE***

As a side note I ended up structuring it a little more simply. As my 'product' sections only needed a name and id they lent themselves to key value pairs as per appSettings. So I created a section like this:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="productGroup"
           type="System..Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"
           allowLocation="true"
           allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
</configSections>
```

Note that I changed the type. My productGroup then looked like this:

```
<productGroup>
  <add key="product1" value="1" />
  <add key="product2" value="2" />
</productGroup>
```

I then could remove the ProductSection class altogether and just reference my group of products like this:

```
var products = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("productGroup") as NameValueCollection;

if (products.AllKeys.Contains(myProduct))
{
    var myValue = products[myProduct];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice 2 things

**A configuration section can only appear 1 time within a configuration file.**
The full initialization exception shows:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> 
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: **Sections must only appear once per config file**.

This means you can only have 1 `product` section:

```
<productGroup>
    <product name="my name" id="1" />       
</productGroup>
```

If you need multiple, you need to declare multiple sections with **unique section names**:

```
<configuration>
    <sectionGroup name="productGroup">
        <section name="product" type="myProject.Stuff.Api.ProductSection" />
        <section name="product2" type="myProject.Stuff.Api.ProductSection" />
    </sectionGroup>

    <!-- Other configuration elements -->

    <productGroup>
        <product name="my name" id="1" />
        <product2 name="my name 2" id="2" />
    </productGroup>
</configuration>
```

---

It is a best practice to declare the section in `app/web.config` with its **fully qualified assemblyname**,
which includes the name of the assembly (without file extension).
This is a must if the class/section is defined in an external assembly; here `ProductionSection` is defined in an assembly other than the one of the main unittest.

Declare the section as below in the `App.config` file of your unittest project.
(Replace *NameOfTheAssemblyContainingTheProductSectionClass with the name of your assembly.*)

```
<section
    name="product"
    type="myProject.Stuff.Api.ProductSection, NameOfTheAssemblyContainingTheProductSectionClass"             
    />
```